# Ranking unique values Snowflake based on created_at

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to rank unique string values in Snowflake based on `n_group`. The order of the `n_group` is given by `created_at asc order`. This is the query I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT id,
       n_group,
       created_at,
       dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY vertical_sub_group) AS d_rank
FROM t
ORDER BY created_at
```

**Output:**

```
ID      N_GROUP CREATED_AT                              D_RANK
0001    R       2020-02-29 21:15:21.000000000 -08:00    2
0001    R       2020-03-13 21:30:16.000000000 -07:00    2
0001    F       2020-03-16 20:46:59.000000000 -07:00    1
0001    H       2020-03-18 12:35:05.000000000 -07:00    3
0001    R       2020-03-20 21:02:39.000000000 -07:00    2
```

**Expected output:**

```
ID      N_GROUP CREATED_AT                              D_RANK
0001    R       2020-02-29 21:15:21.000000000 -08:00    1
0001    R       2020-03-13 21:30:16.000000000 -07:00    1
0001    F       2020-03-16 20:46:59.000000000 -07:00    2
0001    H       2020-03-18 12:35:05.000000000 -07:00    3
0001    R       2020-03-20 21:02:39.000000000 -07:00    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` for this, with a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by min_created_at, n_group) as ranking
from (select t.*,
             min(created_at) over (partition by id, n_group) as min_created_at
      from t
     ) t;
```